# Unit Test oAuth2 Authorization Code

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, oauth-2.0, guzzle

I'm able to connect from Laravel via Guzzle with an external api. That api requires authentication via oAuth2 with Authorization Code. I'm wondering how I can integration test the redirect scenario, with only the user name and password?

With other words: how to simulate the browser action with redirect to 'grab' the Authorization Code from redirected uri in an integration test?

## Flow

- I request (GET) the login page of the external api
- I must fill in user name and password
- After the right login, I'll be redirected to the specified redirect uri with de authorization code as query parameter

## Automated Test

- I can connect with the api and I'm able to do GET, POST and PUT requests
- The redirect scenario works via browser, but in the integration test scenario, I only have user name and password, **but not the fields CSRF, viewState, etc.**

## Problem

In the response of the first GET request (to get login form) there are multiple hidden fields (CSRF, viewState). That fields I cannot simulate in my POST request. I only have the User Name and Password fields. So in this case, I never been redirected, but it returns the login page again. Because I miss crucial hidden fields.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Unit testing the relevant logic, or to create an integration test with faked/mocked oauth server?

Comment: I want to get an authorization code from the redirect uri. What's the usefulness of a faked or mocked auth server?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Do you really want to call an external api from within your test, whose success will then be coupled to the external api? Reading your question, I have trouble undestanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment. I want to test real authentication with the external demo api (integration test) without mocking or faking. After authentication, I want to test the real communication with posting XML to that api (that works already).

Comment: @schellingerht I am also trying to unit test the auth code flow. Did you find a solution?

Comment: The idea of unit testing: test a unit without dependencies. So you should not unit test external auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do the following:

**Once:**

- Request the authorization code
- Request the access token + refresh token

**If refresh token is available:**
Request a new token pair (access + refresh) with the current refresh token when the access token is expired.